Twilio conference events are messed up when a reservation is canceled and another created
Encountered very weird bug in Twilio.
So the scenario is as following:

Voice task is created from a customer call using  directive.
A reservation is created to a worker.
This worker creates a conference from the front end using reservaion.conference function.
Twilio creates a call to the worker.
If worker fails to accept the call Twilio cancels the reservation and creates another one to an other worker.
If the second worker creates a conference and then accepts the call conference events are sent to the StatusCallback URL provided by the first worker, and for the most events sent to the URL the payload contains the ReservationSid of the first worker, that was canceled by Twilio.

Very weird behavior. Has anybody encountered that? Any workarounds?
Thank you!
